# Wrong paragraphs order on privileges pages

Tags: bug, privileges, help-center

For example, https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions.

> [image]

"Privilege type:" should be before privilege name.

Related [question on Meta.ruSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10351/).